# Query a ACF field within a Custom Post type using $wpdb

Tags: sql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have looked at and tried various posts and code examples here and I seems to have hot a wall. I have WordPreess Custom Post Type created called 'show'. Each Show Custom Post has several ACF field associated with it. One of these ACF fields is a select field called 'year'. The select list as predefined values (i.e 2022-2023,2021-2022, 2020-2021, etc)

I haved created a template file called pastseasons.php with an HTML select list  (see below)

```
<form id="form" method="get">
<select id="selection" style="float:left;">
<option value="">Choose an option...</option>
<option value="?season=2022-2023">2022-2023</option>
<option value="?season=2021-2022">2021-2022</option>
<option value="?season=2020-2021">2020-2021</option>
```

etc.

I am trying to a query that will return all records where the custom post type is 'show' and the ACF field 'year' is equal to the value of 'season' as chosen by the end user via the HTML select menu and passed via GET (http://EXAMPLEDOMAIN/pastseasons?season=2020-2021

and then create a WordPress loop to display the results.

Here is the $wpdb code I have tried:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$yourposts = $wpdb->get_results( 
    
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "
            SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE 'year' LIKE %s
            AND post_type = 'show'
            AND post_status = 'publish'         
        ",
            $_GET['season'] . '%' 
        )
);
    ?>
```

Should I be using somethung like $wpdb->postmeta instead? And/or is my WHERE statment incorect?

Comment: You need to use here ACF get field function like this get_the_field('year', "your_post_id");

Comment: Trying to follow. your suggestion I editedteh query as: `<?php
global $wpdb;

$post_id = get_the_ID();

$yourposts = $wpdb->get_results( 
 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "
            SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE get_the_field('year', $post_id); LIKE %s
            AND post_type = 'show'
   AND post_status = 'publish'
   
        ",
            $_GET['season'] . '%' 
        )
 
);
 ?> ` but it did not work

Comment: Please follow this and change the query https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

Comment: Thanks now I get it and understand. Its working now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction